# jquery Post problem

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code in which i am sending the values from a form to php page where the query lies and for sending the values i am using $.post of jquery everything is going good. I am resulting a table and a button now i want that button will work and 1 of the table column has the radio button list so i want that button will take the radio id of that perticular row on click but my button is not working so please guide me how i can do this my code is here

```
my javascript function

function searchDetail(searchName) {
    var textName = searchName + "Text";
    var inputText = $('#' + textName).val();
    var formName = searchName + "Form";
    if (inputText === "") {
        $('#' + textName).css("border", "2px solid red").fadeIn(4000);
    }
    else {

        $('#' + textName).css("border", "1px solid #8dd7f6").show(2000);
        $('#searchBox').fadeIn(1000);
        $.post('../search/delete' + searchName + '.php', $('#' + formName).serialize(), function(result) {
            $('#searchBox').html(result);
        })
    }
}
```

my php code

```
if ($count == "0") {
    echo "There is no data with $search = ".$searchKeyword;
} else {
    $color = 2;
    echo "<table cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='7px'><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>book Id</th><th>book Name</th><th>book Writer</th><th>book Price</th><th>Availability</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $checkBook = $row['booktotal'] - $row['bookremain'];
        if ($checkBook == 1) {
            $status = "Yes";
        } else {
            $status = "No";

        }

        if ($color % 2 == 0) {
            echo "<tr class='even'><td><input type=radio name=group1 value=".$row['bookId']."></td><td>".$row['bookId']."</td><td>".$row['bookName']."</td><td>".$row['bookWriter']."</td><td>".$row['bookPrice']."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";
            $color = $color + 1;
        } else {
            echo "<tr class='odd'><td><input type=radio name=group1 value=".$row['bookId']."></td><td>".$row['bookId']."</td><td>".$row['bookName']."</td><td>".$row['bookWriter']."</td><td>".$row['bookPrice']."</td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";
            $color = 2;
        }

    }
    echo "</tbody></table><br><input type=button value=Delete id=deleteButton onclick='check()'> <script type=text/javascript> function check(){alert(Hello);}</script>";

    mysqli_close($con);
}


?>
```

my html code

```
<body>
    <div id="deleteFormTable">
        <span id="headerFont">Enter Information to Delete Book</span><br><br>
        <form id="bookSearchForm" name="bookSearchForm"><label>Search Book:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="bookSearchText" name="bookSearchText"/>&nbsp<select id="bookSearchOption" name="bookSearchOption"><option id="bookSearchId">Id</option><option id="studentSearchName">Name</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Search" id="bookSearch" name="bookSearch" onclick="searchDetail(this.id)"></form>
    </div>
    <div id="searchBox">
        <center><div id="searchLoadBox"><img src="../images/loadings.gif" alt="..."></div></center>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please, please indent your code.

Comment: I dont wanna be a prick but Im really confused to as what you want and mean

Comment: @Val, @Michael means to use indentation to separate blocks of code, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style I tried to reformat it, but it seems to be missing a few `}`. Perhaps that's part of the problem.

Comment: you really really need to work on your punctuation in that question. the second part is simply "all your base are belong to us"! please reformat the question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I know what you are asking.

You have a list of items with radio boxes next to them, once the user clicks one and then clicks the button, you want the "value" tied to that radio button.

If that is the case, you can use this to find the value of the "Checked" radio group.

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function()
{
    var bookId = $("input[@name='group1']:checked").val();
}
```

Comment: Let me tell you what it will do

1.submit the form with the help of jquery
2.form values connect to the php page
3.from php page we get the table with button 
4.now we got the table and the button on our page
5.now i want that button to perform some action but it is not doing anything

Comment: ok so you need to use .live or .delegate to solve that issue. Try $("#deleteButton").live('click', function() ....